# Adding object to enum gives me error

Tags: ios, swift, enums, nsuserdefaults

I have an `enum`, and a variable that points to a certain object in the `enum`.

```
enum Collection {
    case First, Second, Third, Fourth
}
var myCollection = Collection.Second
```

I want to pass `myCollection` to the `NSUserDefaults`. Here's what I did: (I hope `viewDidLoad` is the right place to put it.)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Save the sort by NSUserDefualt
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(self.myCollection, forKey: "myKey")
}
```

At the last line, I get the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'setObject' with an argument list of type '(myViewController.Collection, forKey: String)'

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

**Update**

Does this make sense?

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultRawValue = defaults.integerForKey("myKey")
if defaultRawValue != nil {
    defaults.setInteger(myCollection.rawValue, forKey: "myKey")
} else {
    defaults.setInteger(1, forKey: "myKey")
}
myCollection = Collection(rawValue: defaultRawValue)!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults can only take PropertyList: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html

Try

```
enum Collection:Int{
        case First=1, Second, Third, Fourth
}
var myCollection = Collection.Second

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let defaultRawValue = defaults.integerForKey("myKey")
        if defaultRawValue > 0{
            myCollection = Collection(rawValue: defaultRawValue)!
        }
        else
        {
            defaults.setInteger(1, forKey: "myKey")
            myCollection = Collection(rawValue: 1)
        }
}
```

Comment: You may want to change it to `defaults.setInteger()`

Comment: Agree. Change is made.

Comment: Thanks! That works! This is a side question regarding `NSUserDefaults` in general. If I insert it in `viewDidLoad`, then every time the app starts, that key will get overwritten. Whats the regular way to do it that it won't overwrite? Would I do a simple `if statement`?

Comment: @Jessica use integerForKey("myKey") to get the saved default. if returned int is greater than 0, then means a default is saved before. See edited code

Comment: I added code to the question. Can you please tell me if it makes sense? Thanks!

Comment: @Jessica defaultRawValue will be 0 if Key doesn't exist. You want "setInteger" if Key doesn't exist, otherwise, use the saved value.

Answer (score 0):

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

So, if you want to store your enum in NSUserDefaults, you use rawValue for your enum. Here I use String, like this:

```
enum Collection: String {
    case First = "First"
    case Second = "Second"
    case Third = "Third"
    case Fourth = "Fourth"
}
//create myCollection
var myCollection = Collection(rawValue: "Second")
```

And store it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Save the sort by NSUserDefualt
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(self.myCollection.rawValue, forKey: "myKey")
}
```